# Is there a way to solve the exponential equation $a^x + b^x + c^x = d$ analytically?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

So I came across this equation.

$$a^x + b^x + c^x = d$$ where  $a, b, c$ and $d$ are all constants. And I just wondered, is there any way to solve for x analytically?

Comment: Analytically, I think this has no simple explicit solution. (see **Lambert W function** on Wikipedia).

However, you could use the Taylor series expansion to convert the exponential functions in polynomial functions (*truncate the Taylor series expansion*). The only problem with this method is that sometimes it is necessary to properly choose the center upon which to develop the Taylor series.

I also read once that is often used modular arithmetic (**using Euler's totient function**), but the details of this would be more complex. That area is not my forte, precisely.

Comment: Best you could do is use substitution $x=\log_n(u)$